# Unit Testing in VS / Can't see the full error message for a failed test

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am currently working on a Unit Test for a function that returns an SQL Expression for merge command.
I need to see the full error message simply because I need to see the return value of the actual function.

Instead i get only the half of that result.Here is the error message ;

```
Test Name:  deneme1
Test FullName:  'test name'
Test Source:     : line -1
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00

Test Name:  deneme1
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result StackTrace:  
at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Execution.SimpleWorkItem.PerformWork()

Result Message: 
Expected string length 182 but was 366. Strings differ at index 12.
  Expected: "MERGE INTO [intoTable] USING [sourceTable] ON [merge_conditio..."
  But was:  "MERGE INTO [tsttargetTable] USING (SELECT [tstsourceTable].[i..."
  -----------------------^
```

See the result message is cut in half. Is there anyway to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just write out the line in question and then see the "Additional output" of the unit-test. Click on *Open additional output for this result*

[image]

I'm assuming you are using `NUnit v3` or later. In which case, use

```
TestContext.WriteLine("some string");
```

to write out the extra line. Other test frameworks might support `Console.WriteLine` or their own custom mechanism for writing output.

### EDIT (adding example unit-test).

So, imagine you have a unit-test that looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    var systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest();
    var expected = "INSERT INTO blah blah";
    var actual = systemUnderTest.DoThingThatGetsASqlString();
    TestContext.WriteLine($"The full SQL string was: '{sqlString}'");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Yes im using NUnit v3, not sure where to put  ```TestContext.WriteLine("some string");```  and I can't find any built-in mechanism to find the output. Since it's a test, there is no output really, just an expected result and the actual result and i can't see them both, i mean i know the expected result i just wrote it but , no clue what the full actual result is.

Comment: and also im sorry if this all sounds dumb , im a new graduate developer and struggling in my first real job ^^ @RB.

Comment: @PoyrazKürkçüoğlu I've added an example of how you would use it. If you have any other questions though, kindly first update your question to include your code - I can tailor my answer better if I know the actual code you are using :)